# IBMi / NodeJS: Program IPLUG512K of QXMLSERV not found

Tags: node.js, db2, ibm-midrange

NodeJS v14.18.3 on IBMI / Pase
idb-connector 1.2.15

Hi,

I installed the "idb-connector" for the first time on an IBMi: the installation with NPM seems OK, but when launching my application, I have got an error:

> SQLSTATE=42884 SQLCODE=-440 Program IPLUG512K of QXMLSERV not found
> with given parameters.

On several others machines, it run well, with the same version of IPLUG512K, and the same version of the "idb-connector" (and i never call it directly: it is used only internally)

Comment: Have you compared the PTF level between machines that work, and the one that doesn't?

Comment: no, I'm not specialist of OS400...  But normally, PTFs are supposed to be up to date. I found a lead in the meantime: there are 2 "IPLUG512K" routines in the same QXMLSERV library! I didn't know it was possible...

Comment: SPECIFIC_SCHEMA SPECIFIC_NAME ROUTINE_SCHEMA ROUTINE_NAME  ROUTINE_DEFINER  EXTERNAL_NAME LANGUAGE STYLE 

QXMLSERV IPLUG512K QXMLSERV IPLUG512K 2018-08-11-09.26.49.590000 QSYS EXTERNAL QXMLSERV/XMLSTOREDP(iPLUG512K) RPGLE GENERAL 

QXMLSERV IPLUG00004 QXMLSERV IPLUG512K 2020-12-12-09.36.49.941000 XUMENG EXTERNAL QXMLSERV/XMLSTOREDP(iPLUG512K) RPGLE GENERAL

Comment: Obtain with: SELECT * from QSYS2/SYSPROCS where ROUTINE_name = 'IPLUG512K'

Comment: Yes, it is possible, they have different parameters. It is possible that the parameters do not match what your internal routines send it. Since there are two, it may also mean that you have competing versions of IPLUG512K and QXMLSERV installed. Something is different. It is up to you or your admins to find out what.

Comment: After a little hesitation, we removed the object from the "XUMENG" lib, and the problem seems to be solved. Thanks @jmarkmurphy for your help.